# Can I reference a value from a field in a SharePoint list programmatically in OneNote?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a OneNote notebook I have created. I have inserted a table into a Page.

I would like to have this table refresh itself with data from a SharePoint site.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use JavaScript and reload page in specific intervals.

Comment: @AmalHashim could you elaborate on your comment.  I don't see any way to inject javascript into a OneNote page so that it is actively rendered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While OneNote seems like it should be able to pull data from SharePoint there is no Out-of-The-Box way to do it.  There are no controls (such as Quick Parts in Microsoft Word) and a OneNote page only supports a limited set of HTML tags.  In fact javascript is removed when pasting into OneNote as noted in the limitations in the following link: http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/introduction/html-tag-support-for-pages

If it could do it, it would be from an add-on or custom code using the [OneNote API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575420.aspx).  I did a bit searching, being a OneNote fan, and cannot find any add-ons to pull data from SharePoint.

If you find one or write a solution, please let us know.